# сделать запрет на создание атрибута класса вне конструктора класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

```
class clas():
    def __init__(self):
        a=1
        b=2
        c=3
claz=clas()
claz.d=500
print(claz.d)
```

Как можно запретить создание атрибута извне? Чтобы нельзя было сделать атрибут d из данного примера.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Определить слоты

```
class clas:
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'c')

    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1
        self.b=2
        self.c=3
```

Answer (score 7):

Для полноты следует добавить, что помимо варианта со `__slots__` в версии 3.7+ появилась возможность создавать [Data-классы](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) с атрибутом `frozen`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float

a = Point(10.0, 20.0)
a.z = 30.0 # dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'z'
```

Comment: ¿А интерпретаторы уже умеют с ним еффективно работать, или как в javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Если требуется более сложная обработка запрета, например по условию - запретить присвоение только положительных чисел, то можно воспользоваться [Getters and Setters](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/property-getters-setters)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 1

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x:
            raise UserWarning('запрещено')
        else:
            self.__x = x

a = A()
print(a.x)  # 1
a.x = -2
print(a.x)  # -2
a.x = 2  # UserWarning: запрещено
```

Answer (score 0):

Через **setattr**

```py
class clas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1
        self.b=2
        self.c=3
    
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == 'd':
            return None
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
```